# How to search DropdownList by Employee ID?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dropdownlistfor

Working on ASP.net MVC 5 project.
I have a DropdownList of employees names.
I need to add a search input field, so the user can search employees by entering Employee ID.

I can see the solution as the following, but not sure how to implement it:
- store entered Employee ID in variable EmpID
- store list of employees with their IDs in an array of objects or object of array EmpNamesIDsList
- Loop through EmpNamesIDsList, and check if EmpID equals ID of any employee
If yes, select item in DropdownList

Is this right? or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Do you search employees on server side or just from dropdowlist items?

Comment: @SiamakFerdos I need to query Employees IDs of the employees enlisted in dropdownlist from database, so I'm thinking to do it in controller C#. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I got your point. But you can add a string that combines EmployeeFullName with ID. After that you can search in your dropdownlist either by FullName or ID.

Small example

```
public class Employee 
{
public int Id {get;set;}
public string FullName {get;set;}
public string NameAndIdCombined => $"{FullName} - ID: {Id.ToString()}"
}
```

So that you can use a Select2(or similar) dropdownlist which you can search.

```
new SelectList(employees, "Id","NameAndIdCombined)
```

Hope I got your question right and hope it helps.

Comment: thank you @Pumpkin. I'll try it and give you more accurate feedback